# Bulk Update in Symfony using Propel

Tags: php, join, symfony-1.4, propel

How can I do a bulk update in symfony using propel when my select criteria has joins in them? Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

```
$conn = Propel::getConnection(BudgetLinePeer::DATABASE_NAME);
// Create a Criteria object that will select the correct rows from the database
$selectCriteria = new Criteria();            
$selectCriteria->add(BudgetLinePeer::IDCOL1, $idcol1, Criteria::EQUAL);
$selectCriteria->addJoin(ProjectBudgetLinePeer::IDBUDGET_LINE, BudgetLinePeer::IDBUDGET_LINE);
$selectCriteria->add(ProjectBudgetLinePeer::IDCLIENT, $idclient, Criteria::EQUAL);
$selectCriteria->add(ProjectBudgetLinePeer::IDPROJECT, $project->getIdproject(), Criteria::EQUAL);
// Create a Criteria object includes the value you want to set
$updateCriteria = new Criteria();
$updateCriteria->add(BudgetLinePeer::STATUS, $status);
// Execute the query
BasePeer::doUpdate($selectCriteria, $updateCriteria, $conn);
```

I am trying to make an update(update new status) in table BudgetLine.

**EDIT**: Here's the snippet of the error I am getting:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/proj_ict_new/trunk/cbm/plugins/sfPropelORMPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/runtime/lib/util/BasePeer.php
>   on line 369

This is related with the join statement. I tried to use `useXYZQuery()->filterCon()->endUse()`. but ended up with same error again.

Comment: And, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out another way to solve this problem. Here's the solution:

```
$budgetLine_ids = BudgetLineQuery::create()
                 ->filterByIdcol1($col1)
                 ->useProjectBudgetLineQuery()
                 ->filterbyIdproject()->endUse()->find()->toArray('budgetline_id');

$selectCriteria = BudgetLineQuery::create()->filterByIdbudgetLine(array_keys($budgetLine_ids));      

// Create a Criteria object includes the value you want to set
$updateCriteria = new Criteria();
$updateCriteria->add(BudgetLinePeer::STATUS, $status);
// Execute the query
BasePeer::doUpdate($selectCriteria, $updateCriteria, $conn);
```